# In python how to read lines from a file and store in variable - split by space

Tags: python

I have a file that contains information in the below format
file: messages.txt

```
John Jack 'this is the first message' unread
John Jess 'this is the second message' unread
Kate Mary 'this is the another message' unread
....
```

I want to read each line and have

```
var[0]=John 
var[1]=Jack 
var[2]='this is the first message' 
var[3]=unread
```

I used the .split but the problem that it splits also the message that I consider as one string

```
var= line.strip().split()
if var[3]=='unread'
```

Unfortunately, python counts also the spaces from the message.
How can this be achieved?

Comment: Will the message part of the line always have single quotes surrounding it?

Comment: You need to show us (1) the code that reads the file and parses the data, (2) the input data, (3) the actual output data, and (4) your desired output.

Comment: Does line.split();  line[0], line[1], line[1:-1], line[-1] work for you?

Comment: Yes, it will be in single quotes. The message may have also its own single quotes as well. For example 'This is a 'scam' message'. The maxsplit given below worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming  your .txt files email message body is surrounded by single quotes you can use something like this:

```
with open('messages.txt', "r") as file:
    for line in file:
        # Split line into array
        split_line = line.split("'")
        # Assign each index to a new variable and strip whitespace
        name = split_line[0].strip()
        message = split_line[1].strip()
        status = split_line[2].strip()
```

It will split the string line based on the single quotes and put the data in an array.

- First index - Name
- Second index - Message
- Third index - Status

You can then split the name based on it's empty space if you need first and last names as separate variables.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the [`maxsplit`](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/split.html) argument of the `split()` functions and use `split()` and `rsplit()` provided the data is in the format you have posted in the question:

```
with open('messages.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        fname, lname, lst = line.split(maxsplit=2)     
        lst = lst.rsplit(maxsplit=1)
        print(fname, lname, lst[0], lst[1])
```

Output:

```
John Jack 'this is the first message' unread
John Jess 'this is the second message' unread
```

Comment: That worked fine, thanks Krishna! While I read that info, is there any simple way to replace also the lst[1] with a new value in the file? For example, in a line if 1st[1]='unread' then update the line with 'read', keeping the rest the same.

Comment: If you mean the original content of the file then you need to create the string object and write back to the file.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the `csv.reader` class to read your text file as a CSV. You can set apostrophes as the `quotechar` and spaces as the `delimiter` for the reader's `dialect` property and the library will handle everything for you. This allows you to use apostrophes to disable split-by-space on other columns as well, such as if your email sender had a first and middle name in their `fname` / `lname` field (see the last row in the example below).

Say you have the following `emails.txt`:

```
John Jack 'this is the first message' unread
John Jess 'this is the second message' unread
Kate Mary 'this is the another message' unread
'Martin Luther' 'King, Jr.' 'this is the last message' read
```

```
import csv

with open('emails.txt', 'r') as f:
    dialect = csv.excel()
    dialect.delimiter = ' '
    dialect.quotechar = "'"
    dialect.quoting = csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL
    reader = csv.reader(f, dialect)
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

This gives you two rows:

```
['John', 'Jack', 'this is the first message', 'unread']
['John', 'Jess', 'this is the second message', 'unread']
['Kate', 'Mary', 'this is the another message', 'unread']
['Martin Luther', 'King, Jr.', 'this is the last message', 'read']
```

Answer (score 0):

I would find and remove `'this is the first message'` by using regex (This is in quotes in the file, correct?).

```
msg = re.findall(r"'.*'", var)
line = re.sub(r"'.*'", "", line)
var = line.split(" ")
var.insert(2, msg)
```